# Not able to open the Chrome Browser through jenkins --- unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed

Tags: linux, google-chrome, selenium, jenkins

I have issue launching `chrome Driver` through `jenkins` but the same works in local machine. I am currently using `chromedriver=2.9.248304` and `platform=Linux - cent OS 6`.

Please find my driver launching code below:

```
if(System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Linux"))
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/opt/google/chrome/google-chromedriver");
                            glb_Webdriver_driver = new ChromeDriver();  
}
```

i have added `xvfb`  plugin to `jenkins` and installed in linux machine also for headless execution.

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBdiC.png
```

Firefox driver is getting launched properly with headless execution on jenkins.

Please find the stack trace below:

```
61445 [2016-06-15 08:05:15,470] [ERROR][com.aem.genericutilities.CommonFunctions ] - Not able to open the Browser --- unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248304,platform=Linux 2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.47 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
```

Below are the steps which i used to download teh chromedriver in machine:

*1*- Download latest chrome using wget http://chrome.richardlloyd.org.uk/install_chrome.sh
chmod +x install_chrome.sh
sudo ./install_chrome.sh (u should run it as a root)

*2)* download latest chromedriver (2.9 onwards) ,lower versions will not work

*3)* copy chromedriver to /opt/google/chrome and change permission to 755

*4)* cd /opt/google/chrome
*5)* mv google-chrome google-chrome-standalone
*6)* cp chrome google-chrome
*7)* cp google-chrome-standalone google-chromedriver
*8)* open google-chromedriver in vi editor and change following line  (last line in file )

```
exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$@"
TO
```

exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chromedriver"  "$@"

8) now replace existing symbolic links

First remove existing

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/chromedriver
sudo rm /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

Create new ones

```
 sudo ln -s /opt/google/chrome/google-chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
 sudo ln -s /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome-standalone /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

You are really behind on ChromeDriver, and are apparently using the latest version of Chrome.  Assuming you are running Chrome 51, you will need to be running ChromeDriver 2.22.  See on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromedriver-users/gHBeYvrIOu4).